# How to test update of Windows 8.1 appx app?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

My use case, I have **Windows 8.1 XAML app v1.0** in appx package. I'd like to deploy this version on my tablet, use it for a while and then **test update of this app to version 1.1** which I have in another appx package.
Is this easily possible for tablet apps? I know that for Windows Phone there is Application Deployment Tool, but for Windows 8.1 there is nothing I know about.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as your tablet is running Windows 8.1 you can side-load the app onto it.

Create the app package using Visual Studio.  Then run the Powershell script on your tablet to install the package.  (You will be required to have a developer license on the tablet).  When you are ready to test the next version just follow the same steps.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975356.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Create